# Why is the modal view controller not being presented in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, modalviewcontroller

My application presents a modal view controller (a passcode entry form) whenever the application is run.  I present the view controller in two application delegate methods:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:self.passcodeViewController animated:NO];
    //...
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if (!self.passcodeViewController.view.window) {
        [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:self.passcodeViewController animated:NO];
    }
}
```

The call to present the modal view controller in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method does not present the view controller, where as the call in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` does.  Why is this?

**EDIT**:  I wanted to mention, per the comments below, that I'm using a Storyboard and that self.window.rootViewController does indeed point to an object (basically, it's not nil)

Comment: How is the rootViewController getting assigned to the window?  MainWindow.xib?  Storyboard?  My guess is that either self.window or self.window.rootViewController has not been assigned yet in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: storyboard - I forgot to mention that self.window.rootViewController does point to a view controller, ie. it's not nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) Protocol Manual Reference:

> It is called after your application has been launched and its main nib
>   file has been loaded. At the time this method is called, your
>   application is in the inactive state.

Comment: if the main nib (or in my case the storyboard) has been loaded.  Why then would calling to add another view on top of this view not work?

Comment: Hmmm so the problem is not that the method is not being called when you want to? I suppose you have tried adding a `NSLog` statement to see exactly when it's called. The reason why the view wouldn't be presented is because either the NavigationController is not a the current responder or probably, it is being presented but in another layer or hierarchy level of the views.